# Group GridView in Template10 applictaion

Tags: gridview, uwp

I have a template 10 application and want to use a group gridview. What is the type is need to use to have a grouped gridview in de modelview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a grouped gridview you need to use a collectionViewSource as part of your Grid Resources.

```
<Grid.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="abc" IsSourceGrouped="true" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.DataList, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

You then have your GridView bouned to the CollectionViewSource:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource abc}}" ...
```

You have to fill the CollectionViewSource with a List. Where the MyObjectsneed to be the following structure:

```
public class MyObjects: List<object>
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```